# Yii2 - filter strtolower, but save the without lowering characters

Tags: yii, yii2

I have this rule:

```
['name', 'filter', 'filter'=>'strtolower'],
```

is it possible to use the rule only for validation, but to save the normal string (without the filter)?

Comment: I don't understand - you only want to allow lowercase letters, but want to keep uppercase letters afterwards? Huh? Is it because it doesn't work with unicode? `mb_strtolower` fixes that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is:

you add a property to your model call it whatever

```
public $notFiltered;
```

add beforeValidate method

```
protected function beforeValidate()
{
    $this->notFiltered = $this->yourPropertyToValidate;
    return parent::beforeValidate();
}
```

then add before save to the model

```
protected function beforeSave()
{
   $this->yourPropertyToValidate = $this->notFiltered;
   return parent::beforeSave()
}
```

That should bypass it.